# Date format not passing through to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, date-format

For some reason the date format is not passing to my view, I have used the following in my model:-

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

then in my view

```
@model.Date
```

and the output in the browser is

```
20/11/2013 00:00:00
```

it always adds the "00:00:00" even though time is not on the sql field and ive applied formatting to it.

does anyone know whats up?

Thanks

Comment: The DateTime type always has a time element,even if it's 0. You'll have to change the display format on the View.

Comment: @Alex in your view, are you using the HtmlHelper or just emitting the model field directly? The data annotations don't automatically work, they are there as a hint to the HtmlHelper methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

> @model.Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: I get "No overload to string takes 1 arguments"?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry... Because your Date is nullable you have to add .Value So your View should be like @Model.Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" But be careful! If you have a null in your Date variable and you call a ToString() on it you will get an error...

Comment: You also won't need [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] in your class anymore

Answer (score 0):

`@model.Date` just calls a ToString() on that property, and that uses the formatting settings according to the current culture.

The `[DisplayFormat]` attribute is used by the MVC model binding methods, such as `Display()/DisplayFor()` and `Editor()/EditorFor()`.